# How to update the <version> in a nuspec file in a frontend kit using Gulp?

Tags: version-control, gulp, nuget, frontend, nuspec

I have a static frontend tool kit that will output Javascript and SCSS files that will be consumed by Azure DevOps pipelines.

Our files are setup with each "component" having it's own folder that contains it's dependent JS and SCSS files. Our Deployment manager would like to have a nuspec file in each of these component folders that updates the version number if there is a revision on the JS file.

Is there are way to accomplish this using Gulp?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata minClientVersion="3.3">
        <id>FE.whiteLabel.Assets-and-css</id>
        <version>0.0.0</version>
        <authors>IT</authors>
        <owners>FE Team</owners>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <description>Compiled white label scripts</description>
        <copyright>IT 2019</copyright>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="\js\main.js" target="content\assets\js" />
        <file src="\images\**\*.*" target="content\assets\images" />
        <file src="\css\**\*.*" target="content\assets\styles" />
    </files>
</package>
```

Comment: Is there a central source for that version number, like the `package.json` number, or a system to automatically determine the version number, or is it decided and changed by hand?